# upload photos videos from iphone to ssh location?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible to upload photos from iphone to an ssh location on local network? 
I have a local NAS setup at home that is running plex that shares media with rest of family members. So I want to know if there is a way to upload photos and videos to an ssh location ?

Comment: Regarding ssh, the only suggestion I'd have is sync with your computer (e.g., Photos app on Mac OS) and then setting up convenient transfer using Terminal preference settings (e.g., default Terminal folder location, etc...). But I'm wondering if you are aware of the google Photos features that make all of this much easier, is free, has unlimited photo and video uploads, and many sharing options? Not selling it, it's just that's what I've used for years and after struggling & wasting time with other solutions years ago, I find it incredible.

Comment: I bought FExplorer Pro that helps me upload using sftp